# Passing a variable through function

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I submit my form on my main index I am trying to pass a variable call `$store_id` to a function on same controller called **do_upload_image($store_id)**

I am trying to be able to get the last id that was inserted in my store table.

It works fine when loading another model function $this->example_model->add($store_id); but not when doing it on another function on same controller.

**Error Output**

```
Column 'store_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `setting` (`store_id`, `group`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, 'config', 'config_image', 'flagnz.png')
```

Like so

```
$store_id = $this->model_store_add->add_store(); // this way should let me get id that was inserted.

$this->do_upload_image($store_id);
```

**How am I able to get the $store_id to pass through another function on same controller? I have a model which trying to pass the store id to on do_upload_image**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Store_add extends MX_Controller {

public $store_id;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if (!$this->session->userdata('isLogged')) {
        redirect('admin');
    }

    $this->load->model('admin/setting/model_store_add');
    $this->load->model('admin/setting/model_store_get');

    $this->lang->load('admin/setting/store_add', $this->settings->get('config_admin_language'));
}

public function index() 

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_image', 'Store Image','callback_do_upload_image');

    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

        return $this->load->view('setting/store_add.tpl');

    } else {

        // $store id lets me get id that was inserted from store table
        $store_id = $this->model_store_add->add_store();

        $this->model_store_add->add_config_meta_title($store_id); // Works

        $this->do_upload_image($store_id);


        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('text_success'));

        redirect('admin/setting/store');

    }
}

public function do_upload_image($store_id) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './image/upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_ext_allowed');
    $config['max_size'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_max_size');
    $config['overwrite'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_overwrite');
    $config['max_width'] = '*';
    $config['max_height'] = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['config_image']['tmp_name'])) {

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('config_image')) {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('do_upload_image',  $this->upload->display_errors('<b>config_image</b>' .' '));

            return false;

        } else {

            $resize_data = $this->upload->data();

            $config_resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config_resize['source_image'] = './image/upload/' . $resize_data['file_name'];
            $config_resize['new_image'] =  './image/cache/' . $resize_data['file_name'];
            $config_resize['maintain_ratio'] = false;
            $config_resize['create_thumb'] = false;
            $config_resize['width'] = 100;
            $config_resize['height'] = 100;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_resize);
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config_resize);

            if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {

                $this->sessions->set_flashdata('error', $this->image_lib->display_errors());

                redirect('admin/setting/setting');

            } else {

                $this->model_store_add->add_config_image($store_id, $this->upload->data());

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Model on do_upload_image

```
public function add_config_image($store_id = 0, $file_data = array()) {

    $file_data = $this->upload->data();

    $data = array(
        'store_id' => $store_id,
        'group' => "config",
        'key' => "config_image",
        'value' => $file_data['file_name']
    );

    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix. 'setting');

}
```

Model add

```
public function add_store() {
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('config_name'),
        'url' => $this->input->post('config_url'),
        'ssl' => $this->input->post('config_ssl')
    );

    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'store');
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: There is no reason why the code sample you provided shouldn't work. What does `var_dump($store_id)` give you inside `do_upload_image()`?

Comment: keeps on saying store id can not be null I did var dump with exit at end but error still shows just seems not to work with the do_upload_image

Comment: I have narrowed the problem down it is some thing to do with the resize section effecting. So have just taken it back so just upload part put model in and uploads to database OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have narrowed down my own problem. I need to pass the store id a second time as a if statement and now all works

I just removed the resize function for testing to see if that was issue but now no why. Also need to add return true below for callback function.

```
public function do_upload_image($store_id) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './image/upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_ext_allowed');
    $config['max_size'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_max_size');
    $config['overwrite'] = $this->settings->get('config_file_overwrite');
    $config['max_width'] = '*';
    $config['max_height'] = '*';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('config_image')) {

        if ($store_id) {

            $this->model_store_add->add_config_image($store_id, $this->upload->data());

        }

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}
```